# extend self in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It seems that this two pieces of codes do the same job, but I would like to understand why I'd rather use one or another

**First example:**

```
module MyModule 
  extend self

  def first_method
  end

  def second_method
  end

end
```

**Second example:**

```
module MyModule 

  def self.first_method
  end

  def self.second_method
  end

end
```

Comment: This is a pure Ruby question so it should not have a Rails tag. One consequence is that readers who have filtered out Rails questions (but not Ruby questions) will not see your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first example defines two instance methods and makes them also available as class (or module) methods via `extend`:

```
module MyModule 
  def first_method; end
  def second_method; end
end

MyModule.instance_methods         #=> [:second_method, :first_method]
MyModule.methods - Module.methods #=> []

MyModule.extend MyModule

MyModule.instance_methods         #=> [:second_method, :first_method]
MyModule.methods - Module.methods #=> [:second_method, :first_method]
```

Whereas your second example just defines two class (or module) methods and no instance methods:

```
module MyModule 
  def self.first_method; end
  def self.second_method; end
end

MyModule.instance_methods         #=> []
MyModule.methods - Module.methods #=> [:second_method, :first_method]
```

The first variant can be useful when you want to provide some utility functions that can be called as:

```
MyModule.first_method
```

or be included in other modules / classes:

```
class Foo
  include MyModule

  def another_method
    first_method     # <- no explicit receiver needed
  end
end
```

Ruby also provides the helper method [`module_function`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Module.html#method-i-module_function) to define methods that way:

```
module MyModule
  def first_method
  end
  module_function :first_method
end
```

It adds the method as a class methods and makes the instance method *private*. It's how the methods in `Kernel` work.

Comment: thanks for taking time and for your clear example :)

Comment: Since you've gone this far, consider also mentioning the `self.included(klass)` idiom for including some methods and extending others.